# Android MediaRecorder Class: Does the setOutputFile() method append data to the existing file?

Tags: android, audio, file-io, media

I am using `MediaRecorder` in my Android app. I referred to the online documentation for the `public void setOutputFile (String path)` of the `MediaRecorder` class but couldn't find information as to whether it overwrites an existing file at the same path or appends to the existing file, if it exists.

So, two questions:

1. Does `public void setOutputFile (String path)` overwrite the file at `path`, if it exists, or it appends to the file at `path`?
2. Is there any way to resume an already paused recording which is saved at a particular path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far from my finding, I conclude that the Android API currently does not provide an option to resume recording using `MediaRecorder`.

So manage my target of merging two recorded audio, I went with direct merging of two files by skipping the headers from the second file.

Following is my code for reference:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);

    /* If the voiceMessage in consideration is a PAUSED one, then we should 
     * record at a new alternate path so that earlier recording does not get overwritten, and can be used later for merging */
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "VoiceMessageManager:recordVoiceMessage() - state of voice message - " + voiceMessage.getVoiceMessageState());

    mRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);

    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.prepare();
    mRecorder.start();
```

And my code for combining the two audio files is as follows:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... filePaths) {
         try {
                String originalVoiceMessageRecording = filePaths[0];
                String newVoiceMessageRecording = filePaths[1];

                File outputFile = new File(originalVoiceMessageRecording);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true); // Second parameter to indicate appending of data

                File inputFile = new File(newVoiceMessageRecording);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Length of outputFile: " + outputFile.length() + " and Length of inputFile: " + inputFile.length() );

                byte fileContent[]= new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
                fis.read(fileContent);// Reads the file content as byte from the list.

                /* copy the entire file, but not the first 6 bytes */
                byte[] headerlessFileContent = new byte[fileContent.length-6];
                for(int j=6; j<fileContent.length;j++){
                    headerlessFileContent[j-6] = fileContent[j];
                }
                fileContent = headerlessFileContent;

                /* Write the byte into the combine file. */
                fos.write(fileContent);

                /* Delete the new recording as it is no longer required (Save memory!!!) :-) */
                File file = new File(newVoiceMessageRecording); 
                boolean deleted = file.delete();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New recording deleted after merging: " + deleted);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Successfully merged the two Voice Message Recordings");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Length of outputFile after merging: " + outputFile.length());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while merging audio file: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        return null;
     }
```

In short what I am doing is - skipping the headers of the second file (The length of the header in [AMR](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AMR_format) file is 6 bytes).

This worked for me and I tested it on Android version 2.3

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time! All other posts were saying just to concatenate the byte arrays from each file, but completely left out to omit the header on the second file.

Comment: Could you do the same with THREE_GP or AAC_ADTS format?  Does it have to be a raw .WAV file?

Comment: Does it make wav